# R with xts subsetting: setting two time ranges for each day

Tags: r, xts

How to get data for two time range for each day?

data:

```
sample.time = timeDate('2014-01-01 00:00:00')+1*60*(1:3000) 
data = 1:3000
my_xts = xts(data,order.by=sample.time)
```

To get data strictly between `1:00 AM` and `01:02 AM` for each day we can doing by:

```
my_xts["T01:00/T01:02"]
```

results:

```
2014-01-01 01:00:00   60
2014-01-01 01:01:00   61
2014-01-01 01:02:00   62
2014-01-02 01:00:00 1500
2014-01-02 01:01:00 1501
2014-01-02 01:02:00 1502
2014-01-03 01:00:00 2940
2014-01-03 01:01:00 2941
2014-01-03 01:02:00 2942
```

but what about data between range of `01:00/01:02` and `02:00/02:00` for each day? In the end should be:

```
2014-01-01 01:00:00   60
2014-01-01 01:01:00   61
2014-01-01 01:02:00   62
2014-01-01 02:00:00  120
2014-01-02 01:00:00 1500
2014-01-02 01:01:00 1501
2014-01-02 01:02:00 1502
2014-01-02 02:00:00 1560
2014-01-03 01:00:00 2940
2014-01-03 01:01:00 2941
2014-01-03 01:02:00 2942
2014-01-03 02:00:00 3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's the fastest or the most convenient way to do this, but it works:

```
c(my_xts["T01:00/T01:02"], my_xts["T02:00/T02:00:01"])
                    [,1]
2014-01-01 01:00:00   60
2014-01-01 01:01:00   61
2014-01-01 01:02:00   62
2014-01-01 02:00:00  120
2014-01-02 01:00:00 1500
2014-01-02 01:01:00 1501
2014-01-02 01:02:00 1502
2014-01-02 02:00:00 1560
2014-01-03 01:00:00 2940
2014-01-03 01:01:00 2941
2014-01-03 01:02:00 2942
2014-01-03 02:00:00 3000
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't think there's a much faster or more convenient way to do it.